# Ps command not running under windows service

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

When trying to run a ps command inside a windows service it returns me an error:

Get-LocalUser : 'Get-LocalUser' not recognized as cmdlet, function, script file or program. Verify if the file path is correct and try again.
C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\ps.test\bin\Debug\GetLocalUserv2.ps1:1 caractere:1

- Get-LocalUser
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-LocalUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

But when I run it as a console project it runs ok! Is there any windows limitation running some ps commands inside a win service?

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ps.test
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        private static string localpath;
        private static string logPath;
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            localpath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            logPath = Path.Combine(localpath, "log.txt");
            File.AppendAllText(logPath, "start->"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd:HHmmss") + Environment.NewLine);
            // Set up a timer that triggers every minute.
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 60000; // 60 seconds
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
            timer.Start();
        }
        public void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(logPath, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd:HHmmss") + Environment.NewLine);
            string output;
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            string batFile = Path.Combine(localpath, "GetLocalUserv2.bat");
            startInfo.FileName = batFile;
            //if (script.Parameters != null && script.Parameters.Length > 0)
            //    startInfo.Arguments = string.Join(" ", script.Parameters);
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = localpath;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            try
            {
                using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
                {
                    output = exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                output = ex.Message;
                // Log error.
                //Logger.Error($"Erro ao executar script {e.Message}");
            }
            File.AppendAllText(logPath, output + Environment.NewLine);
            try
            {
                var test = PowerShell.Create().AddScript("Get-LocalUser").Invoke();
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logPath, "test->" + test);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                output = ex.Message;
            }
            File.AppendAllText(logPath, output + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {

            File.AppendAllText(logPath, "stop->" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd:HHmmss") + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're running a PowerShell command inside C# to get user information rather than using the C# APIs?

Comment: Also, are you really using .net-4.0 or are you on .NET core?

Comment: Or maybe use `Powershell.Create`.

Comment: Yes. There's a reason. Because my customer needs to put a .bat and a .ps file inside a spefic folder and this win service just try to run the .bat (calls the .ps) using the instruction -> '@echo off
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "c:\someFolder\GetLocalUserv2.ps1"' and the win service just collects the output and send to the db remotely. They're using .net fullframework 4.x and they found that some ps commands dont run. And this 'Get-LocalUser' is one of them... for example if they try the 'Get-Process' ps command the service runs OK!

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem. After searching the web there're some ps commands you have to enable x64 in the solution. And the service was 'Any CPU'. After fixing to x64 it worked.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localuser?view=powershell-5.1

'The Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts module is not available in 32-bit PowerShell on a 64-bit system.'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).